# Powershell script to query specifc OU in AD for computer names and export

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pretty much(read completely) a novice with PowerShell and I'm working on a project to inventory installed software on some computers on our network. I dug up a script to handle the software inventory part, but it relies on a text file with computer names to scan. I'm looking for a way to query AD for computer names for specific OU's. Ideally the script would prompt the user to enter the OU and path of text file to export to. Then it would search AD for a match and if found export to the specified path. So for example, to export all computers in OU=Workstations,OU=New York,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com" the user should receive a prompt and enter "New York" and all computer names would be exported to the specfied path.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? The intention of Stack Overflow is not for people to post requests for things to be done for them, but to get assistance when stuck on a particular problem.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Sorry. I was searching and found several items that were in the neighborhood of what I wanted in different questions on Stack Overflow. As far as what I have tried. I was using the following but it just searched for a specific OU, and didn't provide for the user input. Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(name=*laptop*)" -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,OU=New York,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it simply, use the Active Directory module in PowerShell.

You can retrieve the computer names with a script similar to this:

```
$City = Read-Host 'City'
$ou = "OU=Workstations,OU=$City,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -SearchBase $ou

$Computers | Foreach { $_.DNSHostName } | Out-File -Filepath "output.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This will work for me. Just a note..when I ran the code as listed, I wasn't prompted to enter a location to save the output and couln't find the Output file. If I enter the full path it does work though. I understand the Out-File cmdlet but what is the -Filepath part supposed to do?

Comment: Great! The Read-Host will prompt if this was run inside a script (.ps1) file, but manually setting the OU works too. The `-Filepath` in the Out-File is the path and file name where you want to output the text to. i.e. "output.txt" puts the names into a file called output.txt inside the current directory. you could also say something like: "C:\folder\output.txt" if you want the file to go somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $City = Read-Host 'City'
   $file = Read-host 'File path'
   try{
   $ou = "OU=Workstations,OU=$City,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"
   Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -SearchBase $ou -properties DNSHostName | %  
   DNSHostName | Out-File -Filepath $file
   }
   catch {
   $error[0].exception.message
   }
```

this will be a bit faster and less memory consuming.

Comment: I like your error check at the end there. Something we should do a more.