# Powershell to query a specific OU on domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Function    ListComputers
            {
                $strCategory = "computer"
                $objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
                $objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
                $objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
                Write-Host $objDomain
                $objSearcher.Filter = ("(objectCategory=$strCategory)")
                $colProplist = "name"
                foreach ($i in $colPropList)
                {
                    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)
                }
                $colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

                foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
                {
                    $objComputer = $objResult.Properties; $objComputer.name
                }
            }
```

This is searching the entire domain. How do I only search in a specific OU in the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=Workstations, DC=contoso, DC=com"
```

It might make it a bit easier?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple different ways. You can use `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit`

`Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'OU=Location,OU=Group,OU=UserAccounts,DC=STUFF,DC=COM'`

Otherwise you can still use `Get-ADComputer`

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -SearchBase "OU=Workstations,OU=$City,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"
```

Second example found here: [Powershell script to query specifc OU in AD for computer names and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994643/powershell-script-to-query-specifc-ou-in-ad-for-computer-names-and-export)